# How can I preserve crisp lines on my mesh with a low res texture, but still overlay details?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, vertex-colors

I'm going for a PS1/Sega Saturn look, with a ~500 tri mesh and a 256x256 texture. I want to use the texture to paint details onto the mesh, while retaining crisp lines between faces.

However, placing seams normally results in UV islands with diagonal edges not strictly aligned to the pixel grid of the texture, meaning the edge between two faces in the same island has a "sawtooth" pattern caused by coloring a diagonal line at a low resolution:

[image: A sawtooth pattern caused by diagonal edges in UV islands.]

As you can see, the top face should be black, the bottom face should be yellow, and there should be a clean edge between them. Instead, the yellow "bleeds" across the border because that edge in the UV island is not parallel to the pixel grid of the texture.

I think somehow adjusting the UV islands so that any edge demarcating the boundary between two differently-colored faces would be pixel-perfect horizontal or vertical would fix the problem, but that will warp the other faces on the UV island.

If I put seams wherever there should be a crisp color divide, my texel density plummets and it becomes difficult to paint details that *should* cross between faces because faces that should be contiguous are scattered all around the texture.

I can get around the sawtooth effect by assigning different materials to the different faces:

[image: Two separate materials creates a clean edge, but where to put the texture details?]

But then how would I insert the painted texture image data? If I try to use a Mix Shader node to overlay a painted texture onto something else (vertex shader, per-face single color material, etc), the texture isn't really painted on top; the colors are distorted as it is mixed with the color of the other shader:

[image: The Mix Shader node distorting the colors of both the image texture details and base yellow diffuse shader.]

I am open to using vertex colors for the "base layer", but as far as I know, any face that borders a face of another color must be a gradient between those two colors because they share vertex data along their edge; thus instead of one face being black and one yellow, one will be a gradient of black to yellow:
[image: Vertex colors creating gradient colored faces.]

What is the best workflow here?

Comment: That's lots of words to read and understand what the problem is without any example pictures... I suppose your main problem is the texture isn't displayed with sharp switches between colors. Have you set the _Texture Interpolation_ to _Closest_ instead of the default _Linear_ in the _Image Texture_ node that's providing the texture?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're right. All these techniques were attempted with interpolation already set to Closest, and you would have known that if I had included images. Really, it's more about UV mapping than texture interpolation. I'm going to remake this thread with a clearer text and pictures to demonstrate what I mean.